# Store abbreviation or complete label?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example to store `Windows 8` I have three options.

```
  1) WI8
  2) Windows 8
  3) Win 8
```

I am not sure which is best. The column is indexed and I use `GROUP BY` on it. As output result I need `Windows 8`. This table does get many INSERT per second. Performance is very important.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question. Are you asking if you can store "apple" and retrieve "orange"?

Comment: No, but for example for countries I've generally seen that people store it in the country code `Germany - DE`. But the output what they want is `Germany`. So why do they do that?

Comment: If performance is very important, the best thing to do probably would be to alter your table structure.  Create a lookup table with all your OSs then, give each a numerical ID, then insert the number into an OSID field in your table as opposed to saving the string.  You don't need to save the text value for each record.  Otherwise, I think the shortest string possible would be most efficient, but may make the data more difficult to understand for people.

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases context, there are two types of primary keys:

- A [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) is a key that is formed of attributes that already exist in the real world: Social Security Number, Zip Code, Full Name...
- A [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) is a unique identifier that is not derived from application data: a correlative integer, a UUID...

Natural keys have the bad habit of changing in time and that adds a horrible maintenance burden. And, in your case, you don't even have a clear candidate, since many aliases of the real world value are expected. So there's little reason to use natural keys in the example you describe.

In MySQL, the standard way to generate surrogate keys in the [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html) feature.

*(Please note that this is a basic concept you must be familiar with no matter what you plan to do. Performance issues in mass inserts are a completely different story and must be addressed at different levels.)*